# Change Assembly Description in Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, console-application

I want to change the description for the console application against assembly on runtime in c#. I didn't find any feasible solution, anyone here to help me out on this?

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
```

Comment: no way you can do at runtime

Comment: Assembly metadata is compiled into your DLL or executable at compile-time and is read statically, without running it. How and why would you want to modify it at runtime?